# Are email salutations regional?

Tags: american-english, british-english, email, letter-writing

**Best wishes** is very popular ending for emails and replaces **best regards** in almost all emails I've received from academics in Cambridge (UK).

At the same time I've never seen this used by American English users.

Is this just my experience? Is there some reason for this? Is this just email or was this present in paper letters before?

Comment: From my experience, probably the vast majority of people who email me do not use any closing at all! I'm an American, so maybe this phenomenon should not surprise me. To this day, however, most of my emails to people I do not know (such as customers for my home-based business) close with the words "best regards." Guess that makes me a freak!? Don

Comment: To the extent that salutations are used at all, they're likely to vary based on the community in which the communications flow, vs by geographic region.  Eg, what's used in Amazon internal emails is likely different from what's used in IBM internal emails.

Comment: Unless it's *thank you*, I don't use salutations at all. But if I did, I would choose *best wishes* over *best regards*. If I were to use *regards* at all, it would be on its own, without *best* preceding it. (Perhaps I should mention I'm Canadian.)